# Como eliminar filas de una matriz de acuerdo a una comparación que se haga en los elementos de la columna 2?

Tags: python, matrices

Tengo esta matriz que se esta generando a partir de Cv2.HouhgLinesP, en la cual deseo eliminar las filas que de acuerdo a las columna 2 tengan valores similares, por ejemplo en la columna 2 fila 1,2,3 hay valores muy cercanos que deseo eliminar y conservar solo uno. Hacer una comparación.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Este es el codigo con el que genero la matriz y deseo eliminar la filas, ya que al dibujar las lineas se generan muchas muy cercanas que no me son utiles

```
#Detección de lineas
minLineLength=300
lines = cv2.HoughLinesP(image=gris,rho=1,theta=np.pi/180, threshold=150,lines=np.array([]), minLineLength=minLineLength,maxLineGap=50)

#Ordenamiento de matriz
lines2 = lines.squeeze()
lines3 = lines2[lines2[:,1].argsort()]
mediax1 = int(lines3[:,0].mean())
mediax2 = int(lines3[:,2].mean())
lines3[:,0] = mediax1
lines3[:,2] = mediax2      

#Generación de lineas
for i in range(c):
    print(lines6[i])
    cv2.line(img, (lines6[i,0], lines6[i,1]), (lines6[i,2], lines6[i,3]), (0, 255, 0), 3, cv2.LINE_AA)
    cv2.imwrite('LineasH.jpg',img)
```

Deseria que me quedara algo asi

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: @FJSevilla esta es mi pregunta y anexo un poco del codigo, espero darme a entender

Comment: el codigo no se entiende, podrias ordenar esa parte? mas alla de eso, como sabes que filas quieres eliminar? que es muy cercano? y las queres eliminar o solo saltear a la hora de dibujar?

Comment: por favor, no agregues imagenes del codigo, agrega directamente el codigo.

Comment: @gbianchi disculpa es que lo pongo y sale todo desordenado, por eso puse la imagen

Comment: @gbianchi ya logré corregirlo, disculpa las molestias y gracias por tu interes en ayudar

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Antes de nada necesitas definir qué es para ti cercano (En mi caso una diferencia de 4 unidades)

Elegir con qué valor de todos los similares te quedas (En mi caso añado la primera ocurrencia en la lista que no tenga valores similares)

Te pongo el ejemplo:

```
import math

x = [
  [1, 89, 1, 1],
  [1, 90, 1, 1],
  [1, 91, 1, 1],  
  [1, 92, 1, 1],  
  [1, 130, 1, 1],
  [1, 131, 1, 1],
  [1, 132, 1, 1],
  [1, 133, 1, 1]
]
# Lista en la que tenemos solo los valores que nos interesan (Columna 2)
x_ = map(lambda y : y[1], x)

# resultado
res = []
# ocurrencias
out = []


for idx, i in enumerate(x_):
  similar = [ j for j in out if math.fabs(i-j) < 4]
  if len(similar) : continue
  res.append(x[idx])
  out.append(i)

print(res) # [[1, 89, 1, 1], [1, 130, 1, 1]]
```

Comment: Muchas gracias! ha sido de gran ayuda y me ha sido util.

Comment: Nota: Si la lista está ordenada conforme a la columna deseada supongo que en vez de almacenar una lista de ocurrencias puedes almacenar simplemente la última ocurrencia, lo cual seria mas eficiente. Saludos!!

Answer (score 2):

Usando NumPy podemos crear una mascara con la que indexar el array posteriormente. La mascara retorna un array de boleanos indicando si una columna ha de ser incluida o no:

```
import numpy as np

def mask(array,  r,  last = False):
    m = np.zeros(array.shape[0], dtype=bool)
    if last:
        array = array[::-1]
        aux = array[0] - r
        for i,  v in np.ndenumerate(array[1:]):
            if v <= aux:
                aux = v - r
                m[i[0]+1] = True
        m[0] = True
        return m[::-1]
    else:
        aux = array[0] + r
        for i,  v in np.ndenumerate(array[1:]):
            if v >= aux:
                aux = v + r
                m[i[0]+1] = True
        m[0] = True
        return m
```

La función recibe un array como primer parámetro, como segundo parámetro (`r`) recibe la diferencia que consideras significativa a la hora de eliminar filas. El tercer parámetro opcional permite definir si queremos quedarnos con el último elemento (`last = True`) o con el primero (`last = False`).

Aplicandolo sobre un ejemplo similar al tuyo:

```
datos = np.array([[1586, 86, 2070,  72],
                  [1586, 88, 2070,  73], 
                  [1586, 89, 2070,  74],
                  [1586, 165, 2070, 149], 
                  [1586, 166, 2070, 150], 
                  [1586, 243, 2070, 228], 
                  [1586, 245, 2070, 229], 
                  [1586, 307, 2070, 307], 
                  [1586, 308, 2070, 308], 
                  [1586, 309, 2070, 309]])

res = datos[mask(datos[:, 1,],  4,  last = True), :]
print(res)
```

**Salida:**

> ```
> array([[1586   89 2070   74]
>        [1586  166 2070  150]
>        [1586  245 2070  229]
>        [1586  309 2070  309]])
> ```

Si queremos quedarnos con el primero:

```
res = datos[mask(datos[:, 1,],  4), :]
```

**Salida:**

> ```
> array([[1586   86 2070   72]
>        [1586  165 2070  149]
>        [1586  243 2070  228]
>        [1586  307 2070  307]])
> ```

El código posiblemente puede ser refactorizado.

**Advertencia:** El array que recibe `mask` a de ser siempre un array ordenado de mayor a menor (como en tu caso) tal y como está la función, aunque se puede hacer más genérica sin duda.

Comment: Muchas gracias!!! ha sido de gran utilidad